# Check Database Integrity fails

Tags: sql-server-2008, maintenance

My nightly maintenance plans are failing for two databases. I'm not even sure what this means.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Here's the error I have from the maintenance plan:

```
Executing the query "DBCC CHECKDB(N'Site_DB')  WITH NO_INFOMSGS
" failed with the following error: "The Index Allocation Map (IAM) page (0:0) is pointed to by the previous pointer of IAM page (1:747) in object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 72057597046816768 (type Unknown), but it was not detected in the scan.
CHECKDB found 1 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors not associated with any single object.
CHECKDB found 1 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'Site_DB'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (Site_DB).". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

The interesting part is that 2 different databases are reporting this with the exact same page id.  Not sure why that is.

Comment: Interestingly, this exact problem (exact same message) just occurred again; except on a different database.  Something else is going on here.

Comment: More information: This seems to occur after I restore a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran across an [article](http://www.sql-server-pro.com/dbcc-checkdb.html) which gave some hints on how to get to the issue.
So I ran the following:

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604,-1)
GO
DBCC PAGE('Site_DB', 1, 747, 3)
```

The Metadata: IndexId value result was -1.  The article said if it was greater than 1 then drop and recreate the non-clustered index.  If it was 0 or 1 then restore from backup or try the repair.  Unfortunately, neither of those situations cover a -1 value...

So I went ahead and ran

```
DBCC CHECKDB('Site_DB', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

This came back and said if found the allocation errors and fixed them.  Just to be sure I ran DBCC CHECKDB('SiteDB') WITH NO_INFOMSGS once more and it came back clear.